# how to inlude js file from htaccess protected site?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

how to include js file , without shwoing pop-up?

Here `http://samplePoretected.com` is htaccess protected site.

i know `http://samplePoretected.com` username and password.

i tried this but it shows pop-up.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://samplePoretected.com/app/views/admin/default/javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply username and password in the URL:

```
http://username:password@samplePoretected.com/app/views/admin/default/javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
```

Comment: tanx for replay, But it alerts (pop up) with message box You are about to log in to the site "sampleProtected.com" with the username "username_we_enterd_in_url".